# What's the event for when a Branchitem has finished creating?

Tags: c#, sitecore

I have a branch template with several sub items (Data > sub1 item1, sub item 2 etc)
All works fine.

What I need to do is run some code when all the children have been created for that branch template.

Currently, if I try to execute the command OnItemSaved, it finishes executing as soon as the Branch Item is created - The child items have still not been created and hence the code I wrote in C# cannot find the children to run against.

Is there an event for branch templates that I can execute so that my code executes when all the children for that branch template (and possibly their children) have all finished creation?